Copying text files while preserving some differences
I'm trying to build a "homemade" CI/CD pipeline for .NET framework projects + JS clients.
After building the binaries, I need to copy a bunch of files, mainly DLLs and minified JS, to the folder that will be the content of a Docker container.
In addition I've to copy some *.config files.
Unfortunately in these files, I need to keep some differences.
Currently this workflow is done manually with specific Beyond Compare sessions.
I want to automate this by using something like rsync but on Windows.
What I'm trying to obtain is precisely what happens when you get/pull from SVN/git and your local file is modified: if possible, the remote changes are merged into local ones (ok, in git you need to stash local changes and then apply the stash, but the outcome is the same).
I thought about creating a patch/diff file of the differences I need to preserve, and always apply it after copying the file.
Is there any viable alternative?

if git does what you want, why not use git?

Because, as I said, the vast majority of the files are DLL, thus binaries. And I want a copy, not a repository.

With Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you can use rsync.

@cyrus thanks but the main problem is not which software use to copy, but how to preserve differences. Does rsync allow that directly?

With rsync you can exclude dirs and/or files from sync.

@Cyrus I need to keep specific differences inside specific files. Modifications to other lines of these files must be merged though.

Yes, rsync is unsuitable for this.

I think you can achieve what you are looking for by checking in the specific changes as temporary commits, although in your case they are perhaps not so temporary but more like environment specific, but that's fine - the "temporariity" of if is just conceptual, at the core it's just normal commits.

you are not required to use git for everything but you said it does precisely what you want for your config files. note also --work-tree and --git-dir
